# Некорректно работает скрипт

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт, который отображает блок, в котором будет выводится информация из AJAX запроса

```
// Вывод информации о дилерах по городам
//Определяем место для вывода блока
$.fn.find_place_for_dealer = function () {
return this.each(function (i, el) {
    var number = $(this).parent('.link-wrapper').prevAll('div.link-wrapper').length;
    var pos = ((parseInt(number / 3) + 1) * 3) - 1;
    $(this).data('pos', pos);
    });
};

//Отображаем блок с информацией о дилере
$('.dealers .link-wrapper a.link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).addClass('hover');
    var pos = $(this).find_place_for_dealer().data('pos');      
    var el = '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="dealer-full-info"><a href="" class="closebtn-dealer">X</a> Информация о дилере</div></div>';     
    $('div.link-wrapper').eq(pos).after(el);        
});

//Убираем блок с информацией о дилере
$('.dealer-full-info .closebtn-dealer').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('200');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EUcu4/16/

Не могу разобраться, почему в части скрипта

```
$('.dealer-full-info .closebtn-dealer').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('200');
});
```

при клике убираются все блоки `.dealer-full-info`, 
а не только тот, который является родительским для кликнутой ссылки `.closebtn-dealer`

И второй вопрос, 
как сделать так, чтобы повторном клике на ссылку `.dealers .link-wrapper a.link` если для нее `.dealer-full-info` уже показывается, сделать так, чтобы он не появлялся во второй раз ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
//Отображаем блок с информацией о дилере
    $('.dealers .link-wrapper a.link').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var pos = $(this).find_place_for_dealer().data('pos');      
        var el = '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="dealer-full-info"><a href="" class="closebtn-dealer">X</a> Информация о дилере</div></div>';     
        $('div.link-wrapper').eq(pos).after(el);        
    });

    //Убираем блок с информацией о дилере
    $('.dealer-full-info .closebtn-dealer').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('200');
    });
```

Напишите так:

```
//Отображаем блок с информацией о дилере
$('.dealers .link-wrapper a.link').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Послать AJAX запрос
    //$(this).addClass('hover');
    var pos = $(this).find_place_for_dealer().data('pos'),
        el = '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="dealer-full-info"><a href="" class="closebtn-dealer">Х</a> Информация о дилере</div></div>',
        next_el = $('div.link-wrapper').eq(pos).next(),
        not_dealer_block = $('div.link-wrapper').eq(pos + 1);
    // Если сиблинга нет, или сиблинг равен родителю, к которому аттачим дилера
    if (next_el.is(not_dealer_block) || next_el.length === 0) {
        $('div.link-wrapper').eq(pos).after(el);
    }

    //Убираем блок с информацией о дилере
    $('.dealer-full-info .closebtn-dealer').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(200, function () {
            //Действительно удаляем элемент
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/EUcu4/23/)**

Comment: спасибо, работает, хотя не могу понять, почему так? что меняет внесение этого клика внутрь другой функции? а на второй вопрос не подскажете, как сделать, чтобы не отрабатывал повторный клик?

Comment: @Heidel, вторую ошибку тоже исправил. К сожалению, теоретических знаний мне не хватит, чтобы объяснить вам, почему так происходит.